# problems starting MongoDB using homebrew

Tags: homebrew

```
Bobs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ bobhannan$ brew services start mongodb
Error: Unknown command: services
```

```
Bobs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ bobhannan$ brew services list
Error: Unknown command: services
```

Problem also using service instead of services.

Answer (score 0):

There is no command called `brew services`.

These exist:

```
  brew install 
  brew uninstall 
  brew search
  brew list 
  brew update
  brew upgrade 
  brew pin/unpin 
  brew doctor
  brew install -vd 
  brew --env | config
  brew create URL --no-fetch
  brew edit
```

You can install it using:

```
curl -o /usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lwe/766293/raw/75a7907004bbff0eb3b072d1d951be2cfe7e5020/brew-services.rb
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/brew-services.rb
brew services help
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install brew services by tapping homebrew/boneyard (one time):

```
brew tap homebrew/boneyard
```

**Note : Set up launchctl to auto start mongo**

> $ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongo.plist $
>   launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongo.plist

source :http://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew